# Strange result in Java Collections

Tags: java

i am getting some records from database and adding in `HashMap<Integer, Object>` .Then i am adding this `HashMap` to a `Vector<HashMap<Integer, Object>>`.  Now problem is when. I am printing the `Vector`, I am not getting the records in the same insertion order ... Please help.

```
public Vector<HashMap<Integer, Object>> executeQueryAsIntegerColumnNames(String aQuery, HashMap<String,String> conditions, String likeQuery){
    LOGGER.info("Query in Execute:"+aQuery);
    LOGGER.info("Query in Execute:"+conditions);
    LOGGER.info("Query in Execute:"+likeQuery);
    Vector <HashMap<Integer,Object>> result = null;

    Connection conn = connection.getMySQLConnection();
    String concond = this.getConditions(conditions);

    try {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();    
        stmt = conn.createStatement();                     
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(aQuery + concond);    
        ResultSetMetaData metaInfo = null;
        if(rs != null){
            metaInfo =rs.getMetaData();
        }
        while(rs != null && rs.next()){
            if(result == null){
                result = new Vector<HashMap<Integer, Object>>();
            }
            HashMap<Integer, Object> row = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();

            for(int i = 1 ; i <= metaInfo.getColumnCount(); i++){
                row.put(i, rs.getObject(i));
            }

            result.add(row);
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        LOGGER.error("executeQueryAsIntegerColumnNames : "+ex);
    }finally{
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception :",e);
        }                   
    }            
    LOGGER.info("Befor Returning to Caller : "+result.toString());    
    return result;
}
```

Does Vector support insertion Order??? IF YES then This is my OutPut Please have a look

Befor Returning to Caller : [{1=mah0300537, 2=nabi hussain, 3=Mah03, 4=05:50:00 PM, 5=233346, 6=0}, {1=cha0700003, 2=sita sharan ray, 3=cha07, 4=05:50:00 PM, 5=233347, 6=2}]

Befor Returning to Caller : [{1=cha0700003, 2=sita sharan ray, 3=cha07, 4=05:50:00 PM, 5=233347, 6=2}, {1=mah0300537, 2=nabi hussain, 3=Mah03, 4=05:50:00 PM, 5=233346, 6=0}]

Comment: HashMap doesn't preserve order. Use a LinkedHashMap instead.

Comment: may be , if your quey has no order by thne every time it will fetch data in different order , hence while you are adding featched values in hasmap the order is different may be , therefor every single time the prnt order is different

Comment: But why Vector<HashMap<Integer,ObjecT>> ? I think simple ArrayList is more than enough for your code.

Comment: @vels4j [Vector is synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html), so using Vector instead of ArrayList is justifiable in certain cases.

Comment: @vels4j  ArrayList is not synchronized thats why i am using Vector.Thanks!

Comment: Does Vector support insertion Order???

Comment: In the code that is shown the vector can not be used by different threads, so the synchronization only adds needless overhead. @Dharm, yes, Vector maintains items in order, just like all list implementations.

Comment: @Joni Is below code maintains insertion order?? Thanks         for(int i = 1 ; i <= metaInfo.getColumnCount(); i++){
                row.put(i, rs.getObject(i));
            }

Comment: @Forhad When we are getting records from database there also order can change if yes then How??? Thanks

Comment: @Dharm, whether or not that code preserves order depends on what you have in `row`. In the question you have a HashMap, and HashMap does not preserve insertion order.

Comment: @Dharm i think this link will give you proper answer , http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:74320098178823  , may be this article also help you as i am also getting confused after reviewing and testing , http://tkyte.blogspot.in/2005/08/order-in-court.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to maintain order use **LinkedHashMap** .
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Answer (score 8):

HashMap doesn't maintain insertion order. Use [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead.

Answer (score 3):

From HashMap javadoc:

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Use LinkedHashMap if you want to keep the order of inserted elements in a map.

Comment: [`Vector` is not deprecated.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)